# How would I use induction to prove that this map exists?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, induction, functors

I'm self learning Rotman's Algebraic Topology and I've come across the following problem:

I'm trying to prove Theorem $9.12(i)$ (attached in first image below) inductively on $k$, but I'm having trouble understanding how to continue.

I see that if $k=0$ then the theorem is seen to be true by Lemma $9.11$ (attached in the bottom image below) by connecting the $0$'s with a $0$ map, but I'm not sure how to show how the other cases are true inductively on $n \ge 0$.

Anyone have any ideas?  Clear and detailed explanations would be helpful as I am self-learning this.

---

[image]

Comment: Doesn't Rotman give a proof?

Comment: After what I mentioned in the question he says "the inductive step follows easily from Lemma $9.11$".  I can't figure out how it follows.

Comment: That's right: for $k=1$, take $F=F_1$, $G=F_0$, $G''=HF_0$ etc. For $k=2$, that $F=F_2$, $G=F_1$, $G''=F_0$ etc., etc.

Comment: But how would I show this inductively?  As in if I assume it's true for some $k \gt 0$ how would I show it's true for $k+1 \gt 0$?  I'm confused by this because the lemma uses diagrams with two "boxes" and for $k \ge 1$ there's more than two boxes?  I don't see how I'd incorporate $\sigma \tau=0$ in the lemma for larger $k$.

Comment: Would it work if I had the top row as $F_k \rightarrow^{d_k} F_{k-1} \rightarrow ^ {\beta d_1 d_2 \dots d_{k-1}} H_0F \rightarrow 0 $ where $\beta : F_0 \rightarrow H_0 F$ and the bottom row defined similarly using the lemma?

Comment: No, that would not work, as $F_{k-1}\to H_0F$ would usually be the zero map. Use my previous hint instead.

Comment: Could you explain more on your hint?  I don't understand how it would show this to be true inductively if you're just showing it's true for $k=1, 2,$ etc...How would show it's true for some $k+1$ if you assume it's true for some $k \gt 0$?  I've been stuck on this for a while, so if you could explain in more detail that would be appreciated.